# form doesnt set variables when echoed - php

Tags: php

I was trying to echo a form that already worked out when I build up before (without echoing it through php). 
Now that I'm trying echoing this form

```html
echo "<form action=\"timeschedulingphp.php\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"FName\" name=\"FName\" value=\"" . $row['FName'] . "\">
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"FName\" name=\"FName\" value=\"" . $row['LName'] . "\">" ;

}
echo "<input id=\"date\" type=\"text\" size=8 class=\"form-control mb-2\" name=\"Date\"> </input>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.js\"></script>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery-ui.js\"></script>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/ui.js\"></script>

               <input id=\"appt-time\" type=\"time\" name=\"FromTime\"
                                   min=\"00:00\" max=\"24:00\" required
                                   pattern=\"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\" class=\"form-control mb-2\"></input>
                            
                        <input id=\"appt-time\" type=\"time\" name=\"ToTime\"
                                   min=\"00:00\" max=\"24:00\" required
                                   pattern=\"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\" class=\"form-control mb-2\"></input>

                        

                        

                        

                        <select name=\"Class\" class=\"form-control mb-2\">
                            <option value=\"null\"></option>
                            <option value=\"Piano Class\">Piano Class</option>
                            <option value=\"Sing Class\">Sing Class</option>
                        </select>

                        <select name=\"Present\" class=\"form-control mb-2\">
                            <option value=\"WasPresent?\">WasPresent?</option>
                            <option value=\"Present\">Present</option>
                            <option value=\"Absent\">Absent</option>
                            <option value=\"Justified\">Justified</option>
                        </select>

                        <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\" Notes \" name=\"Notes\" class=\"form-control mb-3\">


                        
                        <button class=\"btn btn-success\" name=\"register\">Register</button>
                        <input class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\">
                    </form>";
```

When I go to timeschedulingphp.php and it controls

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
```

it is not isset.. why?

Thank you for replying me and I'm sorry if it's a noob question

Luca

Comment: Your code is really messy. Can you var_dump($_POST); for me and let me know what is inside it?

Comment: yes the code is a tad messy.. thank you for showing me the var_dump, for debugging I was using Chromephp, but this function dumped in a file showed me that I was doing something wrong. 

the problem was here:
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"FName\" name=\"FName\" value=\"" . $row['FName'] . "\">
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"FName\" name=\"FName\" value=\"" . $row['LName'] . "\">" ;

so the isset was TRUE, but not the Fname which was replicated, so it didnt pass another if condition... typo problem here! Thank you for the time!

Comment: Can you try this? `echo '<input type="hidden" id="FName" name="FName" value="' . $row['FName'] . '"> <input type="hidden" id="FName" name="FName" value="' . $row['LName'] . '>' ;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it as submit type

```
<button class=\"btn btn-success\" name=\"register\" value=\"Register\" type=\"submit\">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay According To You're Question 
Why `if(isset($_POST['register']))`is not isset or considered have a null value
Because You don't set The Value of the button 
Try This

```
<button class=\"btn btn-success\" value="save" name=\"register\">Register</button>
```

This Code Will Give $_POST['register'] a Save Value or same as `$_POST['register'] = 'save'`

Hope This Answer Help

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need some information about the differences you can use.

---

**isset()**

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

In other words, it returns `true` only when the variabble is `not null`.

Documentation:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

---

**empty()**

> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

In other words, it will return `true` if the variable is an empty `string`, `false`, `array()` (or `[]`), `NULL`, `0`, and an unset variable.

Documentation:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

Related to your code and your issue, it seems `$_POST` is not set, so you get `false` in return.

You can do a couple of things to check what is inside `$_POST` and what to do it it is empty.

While debugging always check what is inside your data. So for that you can use:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Documentation:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Hopefully, you will receive an array like:

```
$array = [
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three',
        4 => 'four',
        5 => 'five',
];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

Outcome:

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "five"
}
```

Related to `isset()`, and to catch incase the array/string is empty you can do this:"

```
 $register = (isset($_POST['register']) ? 1 : 0);
```

In the code above `$register` will always be set. Read it like this:

- `(isset($_POST['register']))` = 'If $_POST['register'] is set'
- `?` = 'THEN DO THIS' (in our example it will become (int) 1).
- `:` = 'IF NOT THEN DO THAT' (In case $_POST['register'] is not set,
  $register becomes (int) 0)

If `$register` keeps staying empty, please reload your page. By filling in your format and send actually data within `$_POST`. It is possible if you press F5, the `$_POST` data disappears which means the data is empty.

---

Please let me know if this was somewhat useful or not. I rather to give you information so you can practice while doing, instead of getting clear code and copy paste this. If you have questions, let me know.